# Why reputations are not showing for upvoted question

Tags: support, reputation-history

I found one user profile which have multiple questions are upvoted but do not count for it reputation why this happen? Is there any stackoverflow issue or limitation of stackoverflow. See below screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Upvote doesnt add rep after Daily rep limit (200 rep)

Comment: If reputation limit is `200` then why it showing `245` ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation

Comment: @Sadikhasan rep cap of 200 point per day is on reps gained via upvotes. Accepted answers give you +15, these are not capped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hit the [reputation cap of 200 per day](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

You are OVER 200 because of the accepted answers you've received for the day. Three of them...at 15 points each is 45 additional points.